How can you transfer from device to host without stalling commands?
Vulkan seems so complicated and fine-grained in its synchronisation, and yet I don't see a way of fulfilling my need. I need to do this:

Transfer data from device to host.
Transfer data from host to device.
Place barrier so that the transfer (2. from host to device) completes.
Issue commands that read the data on the device.

So obviously 2 has to complete before 4, which is why the barrier's there. But the barrier is STAGE_TRANSFER, which means on the pipeline 4 waits for the read from device to host (1), which is crazy to do as it's not necessary. Is this right? You could have another queue specifically for device to host transfers, but in actual fact some devices don't have multiple queues, at least within the family. Some devices have one family and one queue.
What to do in this case?

Some devices have one family and one queue.
Which also means that device probably only has one DMA controller.
Transfer queues are more or less intended to line up with the devices ability to perform asynchronous DMA transfers. The GPU is almost always connected via the PCIe bus to the CPU, even in embedded devices. This mostly comes down to the convenience of using a proven design. PCIe data transfers can be up to 4096 bytes in size, but typically the CPU can only move much smaller portions of memory at a time. Thus, when software programmatically sends data to the GPU, it's usually 32 bits that have to transfer from the CPU first. In order to make data transfers more efficient, PCIe devices can master the bus and make direct accesses to RAM, circumventing the CPU. This is what a transfer queue is representing.
It's entirely probable that the second move command can't begin until the first is completed if there is only a single DMA controller.
Vulkan is an abstract specification designed to be widely applicable to many different devices. The expectation is that if the ICD is capable of separating the two transfers into parallel operations that can be waited on independently, then the ICD must also provide multiple queues to expose that functionality. A queue after all is a set of operations that will be performed sequentially.
Your only options are to use multiple queues if available, reorder your commands to prevent unnecessary commands from clogging the queue, or to eat the cost of having to wait on the prior transfers. There isn't a magic incantation of commands that can overcome physical hardware limitations.
